# Is moving database works to child processes a good idea in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I just started getting into `child_process` and all I know is that it's good for delegating blocking functions (e.g. looping a huge array) to child processes.

I use [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) to communicate with the mysql database. I was wondering if there's a benefit to move some of the asynchronous database works to child processes. I read it in another thread (Unfortunately I couldn't find it in the browser history) that there's no good reason to delegate async functions to child processes. Is it true?

example code:

child.js

```
import {createConnection} "./dbConnection";
import {SomeTable} from "./entity/SomeTable";

process.on('message', (m)=> {
    createConnection().then(async connection=>{
        let repository = connection.getRepository(SomeTable);
        let results = await repository
            .createQueryBuilder("t")
            .orderBy("t.postId", "DESC")
            .getMany();

        process.send(results);
    })
});
```

main.js

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const child = cp.fork('./child.js');
child.send('Please fetch some data');
child.on('message', (m)=>{
      console.log(m);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big gain about Javascript is its asynchronous nature...

What happens when you call an asynchronous function is that the code continues to execute, not waiting for the answer. And just when the function is done, and an answer is given does it then continue on with that part.

Your database call is already asynchronous. So you would spawn another node process for completely nothing. Since your database takes all the heat, having more nodeJS processes wouldn't help on that part.

Take the same example but with a file write. What could make the write to the disk faster? Nothing much really... But do we care? Nope because our NodeJS is not blocked and keeps answering requests and handling tasks. The only thing that you might want to check is to not send a thousand file writes at the same time, if they are big there would be a negative impact on the file system, but since a write is not CPU intensive, node will run just fine.

child processes really are a great tool, but it is rare to need it. I too wanted to use some when I heard about them, but the thing is that you will certainly not need them at all... The only time I decided to use it was to create a CPU intensive worker. It would make sure it spawns one child process per Core (since node is single threaded) and respawn any faulty ones.

Comment: Your first sentence almost makes it sound as if the JavaScript function itself continues to execute while other JavaScript functions are run. This is not true - all JS code is single-threaded, regardless of being a normal, async, generator or any other type of function. Only the I/O operation is async, not the JS code. This is an important distinction.

Comment: You are right to point this out, I haven't explained it well enough. Thank you for your addition